# Display, sort and filter posts from a relationship field (Podscms)

Tags: php, wordpress, relationship, podscms

I've got some custom post types set up in Wordpress using Pods and linking them using relationship fields. Now I'd like to display (and link to) the related custom posts 'postB' from a single post 'postA'. I also just want to display those posts which got a date in the future, which is also stored in a custom field in 'postB'.

This is what I've currently got so far, put into a theme template file (single-posta.php):

```
<?php
    $id = get_the_ID(); 

    $params = array( 
        'where' => 'postB.ID IN ('.$id.')',
        'limit'   => -1,  // Return all
        //'oderby' => 'postB.customDate, (order is not working, so I commented it out)
        //'order' => 'ASC'
    ); 
    $postsB = pods( 'postB', $params ); 

    if ( 0 < $postsB->total() ) { 
        while ( $postsB->fetch() ) {          
?>
            <p>
                <?php echo $postsB->display( 'title' ); ?><br>
               <?php echo $postsB->display( 'customDate' ); ?><br>
            </p>
<?php    
        }
    }
?>
```

So how can I

- order the results?
- link to these posts?
- limit them to dates in the future?

Btw. is this the right way to get those posts anyway?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use WP_Query too, but since you're using the Pods find() syntax, I'll give you the correct code for what you're after using that:

```
$params = array( 
    'where' => 'postB.ID IN ('.$id.')',
    'limit'   => -1,  // Return all
    'orderby' => 'customDate.meta_value ASC'
); 
$postsB = pods( 'postB', $params );
```

Pods doesn't let you create fields with capital letters though, so it's likely you created that one outside of Pods, correct? Just double checking, if it was created with Pods it would be named 'customdate'

Comment: thx for the help, that works nicely!
now could you also tell me how to filter for posts that have dates in the future and how I would link to their detail page?
btw I changed the cpt names for this post as mine are german, so yes, they are all lowercase in reality. ;-)

Comment: Cross-post on Pods.io forums: http://pods.io/forums/topic/display-sort-and-filter-posts-from-a-relationship-field/

Comment: For future reference, a gist for creating links to related posts: https://gist.github.com/Shelob9/6679914